# provider.azurerm does not support resource type "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association"

Tags: azure, cloud, terraform

I have the following demo script that i want to run:
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/azure-dependency?in=terraform/azure-get-started#complete-configuration

However, it fails at the following line:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "nic-nsg" {
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.nic.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}
```

Which gives me the following Error:

```
Error: Invalid resource type

    on main.tf line 77, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "nic-nsg":
    77: resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "nic-nsg" {
    
    The provider provider.azurerm does not support resource type
    "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association".
```

I am not sure why, I have Terraform 0.13.0 installed.

Comment: that seems correct: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_interface_security_group_association.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved it by myself, I guess the tutorial is a little outdated on their website.

Just change the beginning for Version 0.13.0 from

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>1.31"
    }
  }
}
```

to:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.20.0"
  features {}
}
```

Comment: Tks! The tutorial is outdated!